# SQLYog automatically appending LIMIT 0, 1000 to all queries

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

SQLyog automatically appending LIMIT 0, 1000 to all queries in a database which is causing the below query (`select next_hi from hibernate_unique_key for update`) to fail.

```
Query : select next_hi from hibernate_unique_key for update  **LIMIT 0, 1000**
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 2
```

The same is not happening in other database. Where to check and solve this problem?

**UPDATE**: It seems SQLyog is appending the LIMIT clause, no problem from hibernate or command prompt.
But it is happening in only one database not happening in the other database.

Comment: Where are you doing the query?

Comment: Where is that query being built ? Hibernate does not set the limit by itself.

Comment: But who is appending the LIMIT clause?

Comment: Sorry all, it seems problem with SQLyog.. but it is not happening on the other database. what could be wrong?

Comment: This was a bug and has now been fixed. You can try the latest version from [here](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php)

Comment: @Ashwin, Can I see bug description somewhere?

Comment: Thank you Ashwin, I will try to reproduce it first (this question is so old) and then try with the new version.
Can you add this information as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug which was fixed in SQLyog 8.4. SQLyog bug fix(8.4)-- On executing SELECT statements having clauses like PROCEDURE, INTO FILE, FOR UPDATE, etc., SQLyog was adding LIMIT clause if result tab paging option is enabled. The latest version of SQLyog can be found [here](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php).

Comment: there is no community edition on official site, downloading from http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, it is working fine in 9.33 version. However I couldn't reproduce the part where it is working fine in one of the databases.

Comment: How to disable pagin option?